Aglomerar resultados en una misma pantalla
Tengo este sencillo programa que calcula años bisiestos. Me gustaría saber cómo hago para que todos los resultados se muestren en una misma pantalla; al ejecutarlo te enlista todos los años bisiestos hasta la fecha introducida, el problema es que cada año te muestra una ventana nueva. Quiero que todos se muestren en una misma.
package com.mycompany.bisiesto;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class Bisiesto {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int año;  
        int vd=0;
        while (vd==0) {
            año = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese un año"));
            if (año <0)
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No se aceptan numeros negativos");
            if (año >0) {
                vd = 1;
                int valor = 4;
                while(valor <= año){
                  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "sus años bisiestos son: " + valor);
                  valor+= 4;
                }
         }
    }
}


Edita la pregunta y pon el código como texto para que podemos revisarlo y trabajar con él.

Además de poner el código como texto, con formato: No todos los años divisibles por 4 son bisiestos ;)

Tientes que concatenar los valores antes de enviarlo al JOptionPane.showMessageDialog. Por otro lado tu algoritmo para calcular un bisiesto es incorrecto.
Un año es bisiesto cuando es divisible por 400 o cuando es divisible por 4 pero no por 100. En esta pregunta hay una excelente explicación
Por último, sería bueno separar el código en funciones
1.- Una función que valide si un año es bisiesto
private static Boolean isBisiesto(int year) {
    return (year % 400 == 0) || (year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0);
}

2.- Una función que devuelva una cadena con la lista de años
Aquí recorremos desde 0 hasta el año ingresado y en cada loop preguntamos si el año es bisiesto (mediante la función isBisiesto). Si cumple la condición, concatenamos el año, para obtener finalmente un string largo a modo de lista visual
public static String getListYear(int finalYear){
    String result = "";
    
    for(int i=0; i<=finalYear; i++) {
        if(isBisiesto(i)) {
            result+= i + "\n";
        }
    }
    return result;
}

3.- El main queda:
public static void main(String[] args) {
  int year = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese un año"));
  if (year < 0)
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No se aceptan números negativos");
  }
  else{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "sus años bisiestos son: \n" + getListYear(year));
  }
}


Debes un auxiliar texto que obtenga todos los valores y después mostrarlos por pantalla
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
    
public class Bisiesto {

    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        int anio;
        int vd = 0;
        String aux = "";
        while( vd == 0 ) {
            anio = Integer.parseInt( JOptionPane.showInputDialog( "ingresa un anio" ) );
            if( anio < 0 ) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, "No se acepta ese anio" );
            }
            else {
                vd = 1;
                int valor = 4;
                int valor2 = 1;
                while( valor <= anio ) {
                    if( valor2 % 25 == 0 ) {
                        aux += String.valueOf(  + valor ) + "  \n";
                    }
                    else {
                        aux += String.valueOf(  + valor ) + "  ";
                    }
                    valor2 += 1;
                    valor += 4;
                }
            }
        }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, aux );
    }
}

